# Feint checks in Mutants and Masterminds

Tags: combat, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

In the combat section, "feint" is described as a use of Bluff to confuse the opponent into leaving an opening, treating the next attack as a surprise attack. (So feint is basically Bluff vs. Sense Motive.)

The description of the Bluff skill mentions that circumstance bonuses are given on the Sense Motive if the Bluff "is a little hard to believe or puts the target at some kind of risk." (+5 or +10 bonus to Sense Motive, depending on the magnitude of the risk.)

**Would this apply to feinting in combat?** If I feint, it could put you in danger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a GM I wouldn't apply that bonus to the Sense Motive check. The bonus would come into play when believing the bluff would change the level of risk.

For example, "It's completely safe to take a dip in the vat full of flesh eating bacteria". Getting into the vat is a level of risk way above not getting in. Get the +10 bonus.

In combat and feinting a move like "I'm attacking your head", defending your head and defending your torso are at the same level of risk. No bonus here.

This issue applies to most if not all d20-based games like D&D, Pathfinder and so on as well as M&M.